# Why are folders in home directory (Documents, Pictures, etc) created only after the first graphical login?

Tags: users, home, xdg-user-dirs

I am learning Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. After creating users as root, if I login as the new user using "su - username", there are no directories in the user's home directory .

Once I login as the new user graphically, then these are created.

Why is this so?

Comment: They could be, if `/etc/skel` was populated with the appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These folders are not made/used by the system during user creation because the system doesn't generate them. They are generated the package `xdg-user-dirs-update` (Ubuntu) and `xdg-user-dirs` (Fedora/RHEL).

The file `/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-update` is run at logon and creates the files based on defaults in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`, or if it exists `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

If you want to disable it, the setting is in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`, or uninstall the package, if dependencies allow.

Reference: [Who is creating Documents/Video/Pictures/etc. in home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268720/who-is-creating-documents-video-pictures-etc-in-home-directory?rq=1)